# Why ImageMagick trim minSize is not working?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, scanning

There are some scanned image files. The scan is made larger than the actual content, such that white borders are shown in the image files. I would like to (use ImageMagick to auto detect and) trim the borders, while not trimming so hard (in case the content background is white also) by keeping a minimum size of the image.

Same question has been asked about a year ago: [ImageMagick: trim but keep a minimum size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71148717/1884546). I guess the **trim:minSize=geometry** were not available at that moment.

Documentations are here:

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim

> -trim
>
> ...
>
> Use -define trim:minSize=geometry limit the trim to the specified size.

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define

> -define key{=value}...

https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php

> trim:minSize=geometry
>
> Limit the trim to the specified size.

Previous discussion for adding the trim:minSize feature: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/4861?sort=new.

My trial:

```
# magick -verbose input.tif -fuzz 5% -define trim:minSize=2310x2600 -trim output.tif
input.tif TIFF 2368x2633 2368x2633+0+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 16.915MiB 0.020u 0:00.025
input.tif=>output.tif TIFF 2368x2633=>2301x2586 2368x2633+67+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 17.0247MiB 0.020u 0:00.022
```

`input.tif` is a scanned image of 2368x2633px with white borders.

The above command output is trimmed to 2301x2586px, which is not respecting the `trim:minSize=2310x2600` constrain.

FYI: The solution in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71148717/1884546) is adding a border *after* the trim, which is not ideal. If the content is close to white but not white, it will be trimmed then a white border is added.

Is it that I wrongly used the magick command or parameters, or ImageMagick trim:minSize definition is really not working?

---

#### Edit:

More information about the question.

I just updated ImageMagick to version 7.1.0-48 on [Gentoo Linux](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-gfx/imagemagick).

```
# magick -version

Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-48 Q16 x86_64 20449 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenCL OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo freetype jng jpeg lcms ltdl pangocairo png rsvg tiff x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (11.3)
```

The original tiff image I was working on is too large (17MB) for testing and upload. I downsized it to the following 719x800px smaller png. There are still weird results with it.

[image]

First, try basic trim. It trimmed to 676x784px.

```
# magick -verbose input.png -fuzz 15% -trim output.png 

input.png PNG 719x800 719x800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.010u 0:00.011
input.png=>output.png PNG 719x800=>676x784 719x800+29+2 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.210u 0:00.191
```

Then use `-define trim:minSize=710x799` to limit the trim. It trimmed to 707x798px, which is smaller than the minSize.

```
# magick -verbose input.png -define trim:minSize=710x799 -gravity south -fuzz 15% -trim output.png 

input.png PNG 719x800 719x800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.010u 0:00.010
input.png=>output.png PNG 719x800=>707x798 719x800+12+2 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.220u 0:00.198
```

If we omit the `-gravity south`. It even trims to 690x798px, much smaller than the minSize.

```
# magick -verbose input.png -define trim:minSize=710x799 -fuzz 15% -trim output.png 

input.png PNG 719x800 719x800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.010u 0:00.010
input.png=>output.png PNG 719x800=>690x798 719x800+29+2 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.220u 0:00.193
```

I am not sure how to use the `+gravity` and `+repage` to reset the gravity and virtual canvas. It seems they do not help. In both cases, it still trims to 690x798px.

```
# magick -verbose input.png -define trim:minSize=710x799 +gravity -fuzz 15% -trim output.png 

input.png PNG 719x800 719x800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.010u 0:00.011
input.png=>output.png PNG 719x800=>690x798 719x800+29+2 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.220u 0:00.192

# magick -verbose input.png +repage -define trim:minSize=710x799 -fuzz 15% -trim output.png 

input.png PNG 719x800 719x800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.010u 0:00.010
input.png=>output.png PNG 719x800=>690x798 719x800+29+2 8-bit sRGB 805860B 0.220u 0:00.199
```

I am not sure if it is legit to use `-gravity` in combination with `-define trim:edges`. I find weird result from fmw42's sample picture also. (fmw42's sample picture is more trivial that its border is absolutely blue. It does not need -fuzz.)

```
# magick -verbose lena_b50.png -define trim:minSize=300x300 -gravity south -define trim:edges=east,south,west -trim lena_b50_trim.png

lena_b50.png PNG 356x356 356x356+0+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.000u 0:00.002
lena_b50.png=>lena_b50_trim.png PNG 356x356=>256x306 356x356+50+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.030u 0:00.025
```

Lexically this makes sense. `-gravity south` aligns the content to top. `-define trim:edges=east,south,west` avoids trimming the north edge.

Note it is trimmed to 256x306px, smaller than minSize of 300x300px.

[image]

Trim edges `east,south,west` with minSize is `330x330`px.

It produces 306x330px result, with strange alignment.

```
# magick -verbose lena_b50.png -define trim:edges=east,south,west -define trim:minSize=330x330 -trim lena_b50_trim.png

lena_b50.png PNG 356x356 356x356+0+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.000u 0:00.002
lena_b50.png=>lena_b50_trim.png PNG 356x356=>306x330 356x356+50+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.040u 0:00.027
```

[image]

With `east,south,west` and `330x330`, add also `-gravity south`. It produces reasonable result.

```
# magick -verbose lena_b50.png -define trim:edges=east,south,west -define trim:minSize=330x330 -gravity south -trim lena_b50_trim.png

lena_b50.png PNG 356x356 356x356+0+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.000u 0:00.002
lena_b50.png=>lena_b50_trim.png PNG 356x356=>330x330 356x356+13+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.040u 0:00.025
```

[image]

Yet if the minSize is smaller (`300x300`px). It fails again. Result image is 256x306px.

```
# magick -verbose lena_b50.png -define trim:edges=east,south,west -define trim:minSize=300x300 -gravity south -trim lena_b50_trim.png

lena_b50.png PNG 356x356 356x356+0+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.000u 0:00.001
lena_b50.png=>lena_b50_trim.png PNG 356x356=>256x306 356x356+50+0 8-bit sRGB 121273B 0.030u 0:00.026
```

[image]

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-13 Q16 x86_64 2021-10-29 https://imagemagick.org

Comment: I am not sure you can use both kinds of defines in the same command (minSize and edges). They likely compete with each other. So the results may not be predictable or may just depend on one or the other.

Comment: A trim:minSize for size smaller than 300x300 works fine for me, so long as it does not trim past the flat color region relative to your gravity setting. That would them be limited by the image size. See my ADDITION below.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me on Imagemagick 7.1.0.57 Q16 Mac OSX Monterey.

Input (size 356x356):

[image]

```
magick lena_b50.png -define trim:minSize=300x300 -gravity center -trim lena_b50_trim.png
```

Result (size 300x300)

[image]

**ADDITIONI**

The minSize define is a relatively new feature (7.1.0.30 and higher).  So it was not implemented in your older version of Imagemagick 7.

Also one may need to add -fuzz XX% to the command depending upon the image.

I believe that if your minSize values relative to -gravity  go beyond the limits of the flat color region, then it will limit to the the image bounds or how much it will be reduced by the -fuzz.

It works for me for trimSize of 270x270 which is still larger than the image size of 256x256. So your comment about not working below 300x300 is not accurate.

```
magick lena_b50.png -define trim:minSize=270x270 -gravity center -trim lena_b50_trim2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @fmw42 especially for your contribution in the ImageMagick project. I updated ImageMagick so it should support minSize now. But the problem is still not solved. The question is updated to provide more information. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 - I am studying your code snippet at the github discussion. May I ask some questions about it? In the beginning, the `trimvals` does not take `-fuzz` into account? While `elif [ $ww -lt $minw -a $hh -lt $minh ]`, I guess we need to take care of `$ww -lt $minw` or `$hh -lt $minh` separately. I am not sure if we need to ensure `xo=$((xo-diffx))` is a non-negative number. Lastly, I do not know what does `xc:` mean? Any documentations? Many thanks!!

Comment: That looks like script code. Where did you find it? I cannot answer as it is out of context. Can you give me a link or tell me where you would that code?  The code xc: is the term used for a constant color image and is the same as canvas:. It is usually used with xc:"some_color" or canvas:"some_color"

Comment: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/4861?sort=new#discussioncomment-2447434

Comment: What do you mean by `In the beginning, the trimvals does not take -fuzz into account`?  What is your question about the code you mention. It was just a prototype bash script to do the size limit trim. The actual code implemented may be a bit different and is more thorough than my script.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I will look into it later. (It is late night here now.) Back to my sample image, it produces output image smaller than `minSize` even without `-gravity` and without `trim:edges`. Please see `magick -verbose input.png -define trim:minSize=710x799 -fuzz 15% -trim output.png `.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251183/discussion-between-fmw42-and-midnite).

Answer (score 0):

Greatly based on fmw42's code snippet [here](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/4861?sort=new#discussioncomment-2447434), I have written a script to achieve the `-minSize` feature, tweaked to my taste.

- If `gravity=center`, the cropped area is based on the centre of the original image, rather than adding even margins from the `-trim` detected area. This is because, in case the detected area is biased to one side, the produced result will be less biased to one side, which is more reasonably centred.
- For other `gravity` settings, it acts like the gravitational force is applied from that side. For example, for `gravity=southwest`, the result image is "attracted" to the lower left corner (SW). This is an opposite interpretation of fmw42's code snippet [in that link](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/4861?sort=new#discussioncomment-2447434).
- Last but not least, it works even if `-minSize` exceeds the original image size, and also works for `-minSize` smaller than the `-trim` detected size.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage: ebook.trim.minSize input.jpg 75%      east,south,west 1024      768      north output.jpg

                            input=$1; fuzz=$2; trimEdges=$3;   minw=$4 ; minh=$5;       output=$7

gravity=$( printf '%s' "$6" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/^centre$/center/' )

w=$(magick "$input" -format '%w' info:)
h=$(magick "$input" -format '%h' info:)

trimvals=$(magick "$input" -fuzz "$fuzz" -define trim:edges="$trimEdges" -format '%@' info: | tr 'x' '+')

ww=$(printf '%s' "$trimvals" | cut -d+ -f1)
hh=$(printf '%s' "$trimvals" | cut -d+ -f2)
x0=$(printf '%s' "$trimvals" | cut -d+ -f3)
y0=$(printf '%s' "$trimvals" | cut -d+ -f4)
x1=$((w-x0-ww))
y1=$((h-y0-hh))

# Ensure $minw <= $w
if [ "$minw" -gt "$w" ]; then minw=$w; fi

# Ensure $minh <= $h
if [ "$minh" -gt "$h" ]; then minh=$h; fi

# validate user input $gravity
case $gravity in
    center)     ;;
    north)      ;;
    northeast)  ;;
    east)       ;;
    southeast)  ;;
    south)      ;;
    southwest)  ;;
    west)       ;;
    northwest)  ;;
    *)      printf "error \$gravity=%s\n" "$gravity"; exit;
esac

fixMinSize() {
    trimSize=$1 ; minSize=$2 ; imgSize=$3
    nearMargin=$4 ; farMargin=$5
    nearEnd=$6 ; farEnd=$7 ; adjNear=$8 ; adjFar=$9

    # Ensure this validity:
    #   detected trim size <= defined min size <= image side dimension
    #   $trimSize          <= $minSize         <= $imgSize

    # if $trimSize >= $minSize then nothing needed to be done.
    # if $trimSize <  $minSize then need to expand $trimSize.
    if [ "$trimSize" -lt "$minSize" ]; then
        # if $gravity = << center >> || << north or west >>      || << south or east >>
        if [ "$gravity" = 'center' ] || [ "$gravity" = "$adjNear" ] || [ "$gravity" = "$adjFar" ]; then
            evenMargin=$(( (imgSize - minSize) / 2 ))

            # if -trim detected zone is << LEFT / TOP >> of the center zone,
            #   i.e. it exceeds the center zone at the near end,
            # then nothing needed to be done. Will do $trimSize=$minSize at the end.
            #   No worries, $trimSize <= $minSize <= $imgSize. It won't pop out.
            if [ "$evenMargin" -gt "$nearMargin" ]; then
                :
            # if -trim detected zone is << RIGHT / BOTTOM >> of the center zone,
            #   i.e. it exceeds the center zone at the far end,
            # then shift the trim zone as if gravity={ east or south }.
            #   This takes care of odd number margins
            elif [ $(( imgSize - evenMargin - minSize )) -gt "$farMargin" ]; then
                nearMargin=$(( imgSize - farMargin - minSize ))
            # else -trim detected zone is << WITHIN >> the center zone
            else
                nearMargin=$evenMargin
            fi
        # if $gravity contains << west or north >> i.e. the near end.
        elif [ "${gravity#*"$nearEnd"}" != "$gravity" ]; then
            # if $(( nearMargin + minSize )) pops out of the image dimension in the far end
            if [ $(( nearMargin + minSize )) -gt "$imgSize" ]; then
                nearMargin=$(( imgSize - minSize ))
            fi
        # if $gravity contains << east or south >> i.e. the far end.
        elif [ "${gravity#*"$farEnd"}" != "$gravity" ]; then
            nearMargin=$(( imgSize - farMargin - minSize ))
            # if $nearMargin pops out of the image in the near end
            if [ $nearMargin -lt 0 ]; then
                nearMargin=0
            fi
        fi
        trimSize=$minSize
    fi
}

# Handle latitudinal trim zone shift
fixMinSize "$ww" "$minw" "$w" "$x0" "$x1" 'west' 'east' 'north' 'south'
ww=$trimSize
x0=$nearMargin

# Handle longitudinal trim zone shift
fixMinSize "$hh" "$minh" "$h" "$y0" "$y1" 'north' 'south' 'west' 'east'
hh=$trimSize
y0=$nearMargin

# -trim zone is fixed according to minSize and gravity, actual -crop here.
magick "${input}" -crop "${ww}x${hh}+${x0}+${y0}" +repage "${output}"
```

To test the script, download fmw42's [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEbmp.png). Rename it to `lena_b50.png`. Run the following test script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# One liner test
# ~/bin/ebook.trim.minSize lena_b50.png 123 356 northeast output.png

mkdir -pv fit   ori out
mkdir -pv fitWidth_oriHeight    fitWidth_else       oriWidth
mkdir -pv fitHeight_oriWidth    fitHeight_else      oriHeight

for minWidth    in 0 20 240 256 266 300 333 356 380; do
  for minHeight in 0 20 240 256 266 300 333 356 380; do
    for gravity in center north northeast east southeast south southwest west northwest; do
      if   [ ! "$minWidth"  -gt 256 ] && [ ! "$minHeight" -gt 256 ]; then folder='fit'
      elif [ ! "$minWidth"  -gt 256 ] && [ ! "$minHeight" -lt 356 ]; then folder='fitWidth_oriHeight'
      elif [ ! "$minHeight" -gt 256 ] && [ ! "$minWidth"  -lt 356 ]; then folder='fitHeight_oriWidth'
      elif [ ! "$minWidth"  -gt 256 ];                               then folder='fitWidth_else'
      elif [ ! "$minHeight" -gt 256 ];                               then folder='fitHeight_else'
      elif [ ! "$minWidth"  -lt 356 ] && [ ! "$minHeight" -lt 356 ]; then folder='ori'
      elif [ ! "$minWidth"  -lt 356 ];                               then folder='oriWidth'
      elif [ ! "$minHeight" -lt 356 ];                               then folder='oriHeight'
      else folder='out'
      fi

      output_image_name="output_${gravity}_${minWidth}x${minHeight}.png"

      ~/bin/ebook.trim.minSize lena_b50.png "$minWidth" "$minHeight" "$gravity" "${folder}/${output_image_name}"

      output_image_width=$( magick "${folder}/$output_image_name" -format '%w' info:)
      output_image_height=$(magick "${folder}/$output_image_name" -format '%h' info:)

      expected_width=$minWidth; expected_height=$minHeight

      if [ "$minWidth"  -lt 256 ]; then expected_width=256;  fi
      if [ "$minHeight" -lt 256 ]; then expected_height=256; fi
      if [ "$minWidth"  -gt 356 ]; then expected_width=356;  fi
      if [ "$minHeight" -gt 356 ]; then expected_height=356; fi
      if [ "$output_image_width" -ne $expected_width ] || [ "$output_image_height" -ne $expected_height ]; then
        echo 'error!!'; exit
      fi
    done
  done
done
```

Comment: You should post this to the Imagemagick GIT forum in the same post as my prototype code.

Comment: Yes i know. But i do not have github account yet. Feel free to use, post, or enhance my code.